# Приложение отправляет непонятные символы

Tags: кодировка, php

Отправляет на мыло крокозябры, а надо чтобы русский текст!

Вот сам скрипт

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Simple Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?PHP
    include "libmail.php";

        // Вот тут я дописываю код(начало)
        $email = $_POST['email']; // Email
        $subject = $_POST['subject']; // Тема письма
        $text = $_POST['text']; // Текст письма
        $send = $_POST['send']; // Кнопка "Отправить"
        // Вот тут я дописываю код(конец)

        if(isset($send)) // Если нажата кнопка "Отправить"
    {   
        $m = new Mail; // начинаем
        $m->From( "мыло отправителя" ); // от кого отправляется почта
        $m->To( $email ); // кому адресованно
        $m->Subject( $subject );
        $m->Body( $text );    
        $m->Cc( "мыло получателя"); // копия письма отправится по этому адресу
        $m->Bcc( "мыло получателя"); // скрытая копия отправится по этому адресу
        $m->Priority(3) ;    // приоритет письма
        //$m->Attach( "3123432.gif","", "image/gif" ) ;
        $m->smtp_on( "smtp.mail.ru", "мыло отправителя", "пасс отправителя" ) ; // если указана эта команда, отправка пойдет через SMTP
        $m->Send();    // а теперь пошла отправка
        $m->Receipt();
        echo "Показывает исходный текст письма:<br><pre>", $m->Get(), "</pre>";
        }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="email">eMail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Тема письма:</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="text">Текст письма:</label>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" />
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$m = new Mail("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на PHPMailer, там есть специальная директива отвечающия за кодировку. Класс определяет свойство CharSet, обьекту поменяйте $m->CharSet = "UTF-8"; Хотя в вашем случае может что-то другое. Посмотрите исходный код библиотеки, которую вы используете для отправки сообщения.

Comment: уже все сделано